# asio_handler_invoke const overloads

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, boost-asio

Given the following function implementing an async future.wait() (full example [here](https://gist.github.com/mika-fischer/31fb86ca928162a930c169c98ef1aaf9)):

```
template <typename Token, typename T>
typename boost::asio::async_result<
    typename boost::asio::handler_type<Token, void()>::type
>::type
async_wait(boost::asio::io_service& ios, std::future<T>& future, Token&& token)
{
    using handler_type = typename boost::asio::handler_type<Token, void()>::type;
    handler_type handler(std::forward<Token>(token));
    boost::asio::async_result<handler_type> result(handler);

    std::async([&ios, &future, handler]() {
        future.wait();
        ios.dispatch([handler]() {
            using boost::asio::asio_handler_invoke;
            asio_handler_invoke(handler, const_cast<handler_type*>(&handler));
        });
    });

    return result.get();
}
```

The correct `asio_handler_invoke` is only called when the second argument is non-const. If `handler` is a lambda capture, it's const and the default `asio_handler_invoke` is called. So either the lambdas must be made mutable or the const_cast is needed for this to work correctly.

This all seems ugly and more importantly also horribly fragile to me. So my questions now are:

- Is there a better (i.e. safer) way to implement this?
- Is this an actual design flaw in asio and there should be `const` overloads for `yield_context` and friends that at least give an error message instead of just calling the default `asio_handler_invoke`? Or is there a valid reason these don't exist?
- Or even better, should there be a const overload just for the default `asio_handler_invoke` that gives an error message?

Comment: can't you make the inner lambda `mutable`?

Comment: Yes, as I wrote, making both lambdas mutable is another "solution". However, it's just so easy to get wrong. And if you do, there's no error, but your program has a bug, that is sometimes not so easy to detect. The question is whether that situation can be improved somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Very interesting question.

First off, the premise looks odd. `asio_handler_invoke` is intended for use when invoking *another handler* in the same execution context as some *given handler* (which you cannot know the details about, because it might be wrapped in some (user defined) type).

So I think having

```
F f;
using boost::asio::asio_handler_invoke;
asio_handler_invoke(f, &f);
```

Adds nothing, conceptually and potentially degrades performance (e.g. by strand-wrapping twice).

It could easily lead to undesirable results, too. Imagine `F` were wrapper by Tanner's sample counting wrapper, it would just lead to double-counting the invocation.

### Analyzing the question

So the remaining question would be whether handler invocation does the right thing for built in handler wrapping types, let's use Tanner's counting wrapper, and indeed we see

```
{
    operation_counter oc;

    auto handler = oc.wrap([](boost::system::error_code ec) {
            std::cout << "Inner (" << ec.message() << ")\n";
        });

    asio_handler_invoke([]() {
            std::cout << "Outer\n";
        }, &handler);

    std::cout << "mutable: " << oc.count() << "\n";
}
```

Prints

```
Outer
mutable: 1
```

But changing to `auto const handler` prints:

```
Outer
const: 0
```

See both cases **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b7e8574952d78557)</kbd>**

Indeed, adding an overload to the amount of

```
  template <typename Function>
      friend void asio_handler_invoke(Function function, counting_handler const *context);
```

Makes the difference go away:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/77ff9d15203238ca)</kbd>**

So the weirdness is not that the overload doesn't apply for `const` handler contexts, but rather the fact that the omission falls back to default behaviour **silently and without warning**.

Indeed I'd suggest reporting this at the library devs, because I can see this going silently wrong for things like `boost::asio::strand` which will lead to the predictable problems.

Comment: Have you tried running my example? If I omit the `asio_handler_invoke` the coroutine will not run in the strand anymore and it will crash after a while. Can you give a better version of `async_wait`?

Comment: Also, I've reported the bug here: https://github.com/chriskohlhoff/asio/issues/183

Comment: I was largely confirming your bug, using a wrapper that makes it a lot easier to see whether the correct version is invoked. Indeed this seems to be a problem. Of course, you might add the relevant overload inside the boost::asio::detail namespace, but that ought to be part of the library, I think

Comment: I understand that. And clearly this should go into asio itself. However, I was refering to the first part of your answer, where you said that using `asio_handler_invoke` "adds nothing, conceptually and potentially degrades performance (e.g. by strand-wrapping twice)." And that "it could easily lead to undesirable results".I'm saying that I have found no other way to make my example work than using `asio_handler_invoke`. So I'm just wondering, how you would write my `async_wait` function.

Comment: I never said `asio_handler_invoke` adds nothing (that would be profoundly stupid). I'm not sure that calling it _in that way_ adds anything (i.e. `asio_handler_invoke(f, &f)` as opposed to e.g. `asio_handler_invoke(g, &f)`)

Comment: I have no suggestion to fix the async-wait. I'd probably just add an overload in `boost::asio::detail` e.g. to delete the `asio_handler_invoke` in case the context pointer is `const`. That way, you can prevent silent bugs.

Comment: I was refering to my specific use of `asio_handler_invoke` and did not mean to imply anything beyond that. My point is that quite clearly, it *does* add something here, because if I just call the handler directly, the example does no longer work. And I'd like to understand why. If you think that's not what's supposed to happen, I'd appreciate any insights you have.

Comment: See http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/481830faa1d4c7c9 But it often crashes, so it's better to try it locally.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135943/discussion-between-sehe-and-mika-fischer).